# Ansible module issue with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, devops

Good afternoon, I have a pymongo module that I installed via pip3 and now I am trying to use it

```
- name: Create role for pbm
  community.mongodb.mongodb_shell:
    login_host: 10.0.44.40
    eval: 'db.getSiblingDB ("admin"). createRole ({"role": "pbmAnyAction", "privileges": [{"resource": {"anyResource": true}, "actions": ["anyAction"] }], "roles": []}); '
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: / usr / bin / python3
  ignore_errors: yes
  when: groups.mongodb.index (inventory_hostname) == 0
```

and everything works well on my local vagrant vm, but when I run it on the production vm, an error appears

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ImportError: No module named pymongo.errors
fatal: [mongodb-01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (pymongo) on superproduction-mongo-01's Python / usr / bin / python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter "}
```

OS versions for vagrant and production are the same (centos 7)

python3 version output and import pymongo.errors from production vm

```
 python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Nov 16 2020, 16:55:22)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymongo.errors
>>>
```

from vagrant vm

```
python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Nov 16 2020, 16:55:22)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pymongo.errors
>>>
```

as you can see output the same

Comment: Please check if the `pymongo` module is available on the linux user to which the ansible script is connecting. You can also SSH using the same user and check the pip packages installed via `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip freeze` and see if the package is listed there.

Answer (score 0):

worked even though I didn't do anything